# Encode an array of long values as a BitSet

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I saw that we can encode an array of ints into a BitSet and retrieve them as in :

```
int[] ints = new int[]{5, 7, 25, 100102244};

BitSet b = new BitSet();
for (int i=0;i<ints.length;i++)
    b.set(ints[i]);
b.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

which outputs

```
5
7
25
100102244
```

Is it possible to do the same for an array of longs ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why are you using `BitSet` in this way? The `BitSet` will get unnecessarily big if your numbers are big. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Hi, the longs in the array are positions in a Random access file, the array length can change so I'm looking to a way to store them in one value of 8 bytes.

Comment: Your current code certainly _does not_ store them in 8 bytes. Why do you need it in 8 bytes? I didn't quite understand your explanation.

Comment: You can use an array (or other collection) of longs if, and only if, each long's _value_ is in the range 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE. (And there is sufficient memory available for the largest value; e.g. if your largest value is 2 billion, you'll need several hundred megabytes in your JVM. Neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677938/ )

Answer (score 0):

Use [LongBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/LongBuffer.html):

```java
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

var buffer = LongBuffer.wrap(new long[] { 5, 7, 25, 100102244 });
var bitset = BitSet.valueOf(buffer);

System.out.println(bitset);

for (long l : bitset.toLongArray()) {
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

```
{0, 2, 64, 65, 66, 128, 131, 132, 194, 197, 198, 204, 205, 206, 208, 209, 210, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 218}
5
7
25
100102244
```